# How can I add the text from my input to my article?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I write the text of the input into my article as a p element?

```
<article id="article">
    <h1 id="article1">Articles</h1>
    <p>this is p1</p>
</article>
<input type="text" name="links" id="playlist" size="60">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addLink();">
<style>
    #article {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<script>
    function addLink() {
        var addLink = document.getElementById("playlist").value;
        document.getElementById("article").innerHTML("<p>" + addLink + "</p>" + "<br>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: With or without jQuery?

Comment: if it's possible, without

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a function. It is a property. Use `+=` :

```js
function addLink() {
  var addLink = document.getElementById("playlist").value;
  document.getElementById("article").innerHTML += "<p>" + addLink + "</p>" + "<br>";
}
```

```css
#article {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article id="article">
    <h1 id="article1">Articles</h1>
    <p>this is p1</p>
</article>
<input type="text" name="links" id="playlist" size="60">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addLink();">
```

Comment: This adds to the already existing html while the other answers replace it.

Comment: @PhilCooper, you are right. I think OP wants to add multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is not a method but it is a property so use `=` instead of `innerHTML(val)`:

```js
function addLink() {
    var addLink = document.getElementById("playlist").value;
    document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = "<p>" + addLink + "</p>" + "<br>";
}
```

```css
#article {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article id="article">
    <h1 id="article1">Articles</h1>
    <p>this is p1</p>
</article>
<input type="text" name="links" id="playlist" size="60">
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addLink();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <article id="article">
    </article>
    <input type="text" name="links" id="playlist" size="60">
    <style>
        #article {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var inp = document.getElementById("playlist");
        inp.onkeyup = function () {
            var text = document.getElementById("playlist").value;
            document.getElementById("article").innerHTML=text;
        }
    </script>
```

You can run this, in this snippet, article changes on typing